# How does an off balance Load affect Direct Drive Dc Motors on a robotic "vehicle"

Tags: classical-mechanics

I write the autonomous program for my local robotics team. The robot has 4 wheels directly fixed to an Andy Mark motor. there is no leveling or balancing system. due to placement of different modules with in the robot each side is under a different amount of stress due to weight. The off balanced weight causes the robot to drive slightly to the left when it should be driving straight. I believe this can be fixed by Throttling the power(thus Throttling the RPM). so I plan to place a scale under each of the motors (4 at one time) to show the weight that each motor must pull. I believe if I convert that to a percent of the total weight and subtract it from 25

(percent of load - 25(expected percent) =(percent to compensate for)

x = percent to compensate for

with this the equation would look like

Front Left Power = ((desired power value)+x)

Hopefully I was clear enough but if there is anything I'm missing or anyone has any suggestions I would appreciate it greatly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The 'power proportional to weight' algorithm is unlikely to be completely correct.   If your wheels deform under load, that deformation may be changing the effective
radius of a driven wheel, not only the retarding force.  That would
call for load compensation of velocity, not power.

In forward acceleration, we can see from F= mA, the
power to left wheels and right wheels ought to be corrected for the
left/right mass distribution (so as not to apply torque around the
center of mass).  Both left wheels can be treated equally,
and both right wheels likewise; front-back weight distribution is not relevant,
for this correction.

A differential gear, as in an automobile, is a good solution for two driven wheels and one motor.   Do you need four motors for some reason?

Comment: These wheels work similar to the way a tank drives. they do not pivot so a drive system designed to use a differential, though would be nice, is unlikely to be worth the reward. we only have about 3 months to build this robot. we are apart of First Tech Challenge.